# JavaFX not rendering via gluonfx:nativerun on graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1

Tags: javafx, graalvm, gluon, gluonfx

I am trying to use gluon's substrate graalvm native-image on Ubuntu 22.04. When you run using mvn gluonfx:run on the examples, for instance HelloFXML, none of the text is displayed, as some of our controls in my app.

`mvn gluonfx:nativerun` produces the output below.

[image]

`mvn gluonfx:run` produces the output which is what is expected below:

[image]

This is using graalvm-svm-java17-linux-gluon-22.1.0.1.

Has anyone else run into this issue and found a work around?

Comment: You're positioning this as specific to graalvm, but have you tested to that effect? That is, do we know that the same issue _doesn't_ happen with the equivalent OpenJDK build?

Comment: It works fine with openjdk-17.

Comment: Have you tried setting different font or css for the button? Can you print out the button text when clicked running the native executable? Have you checked the logs for a possible indication? Have you tried adding other nodes (like a Label)?

Comment: "works fine with openjdk-17" -- that should be included in the question.

Comment: Yes, I have tried different fonts for the button. This issue only exists on a native executable. There is nothing in the logs, but when the application starts up with
com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup it gives Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @71c7db30'. But this occurs under openjdk-17.

I also tried a Gluon app and it does it as well.

Comment: I just tested this on Windows and it is working fine. This appears to be only a Linux issue. I am going to go buy a Mac and I'll let you know what I find.